# How to pass the control name to sub procedure

Tags: vb6

I want to pass the control name to sub procedure.

```
LoadDetails grid1

Sub LoadDetails(grid1 as string)
    Dim a as control
    a = grid1
    ...
```

Above code is showing error as

> object variable or with block variable not set

How to solve this problem.

Need vb6 code help

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Your current code fails because you are trying to allocate a string to an object reference. You can only use "Set" to set an object reference, and the right hand side of the "Set" statement must evaluate to an object of a compatible object type. It would help if you revealed to us *what* you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gopal Still adding the "Need vb6 code help".. As I've said mainy times, it's not needed. It's implied in the tags and the very fact that you're asking a question.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to assign a string (grid1) to a control (a).
If you can, pass the control itself instead of the name of the control:

```
LoadDetails grid1 'grid1 is here of type Control

Sub LoadDetails(a as Control)
    ...
```

grid1 is now the control instead of the name of the control. You will need to change the code before `LoadDetails grid1`. Even better would be if you know the type of the control. If for example the control is a MSFlexGrid, you can use this:

```
LoadDetails grid1 'grid1 is a MSFLexGrid

Sub LoadDetails(a as MSFlexGrid)
    'Do stuff with the grid
```

If it's not possible to pass the control itself, you can use this method to find the control with a given name:

```
Me.Controls(sName)
```

(thanks Deanna for pointing me to this function)

In your code:

```
LoadDetails grid1 'grid1 is here a string, like in your original code

Sub LoadDetails(grid1 as string)
    Dim a as control
    a = Me.Controls(grid1)
    ...
```

Comment: They can also use `Me.Controls(sName)` I think.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter is incorrect.  You should change it like this (example with a text box control).

```
Private Sub HighlightText(ByRef txtBox As TextBox)

    txtBox.SelStart = 0
    txtBox.SelLength = Len(txtBox.Text)

End Sub
```

The code example will highlight the contents of a text box control.  The important part, though, is that you can declare a parameter as a control type, and then use it directly within the sub.